# Call to member function selection

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm just trying to create a simple library of functions with my database autoloaded already and I'm getting this: Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object in /home/xtremer/public_html/kowmanager/application/libraries/kow_auth.php on line 22

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Kow_auth
{
function _construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}

function get_login_type() 
{
    $this->db->select('login_types.login_type');
    $this->db->from('settings');
    $this->db->join('login_types', 'login_types.id = settings.login_types_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row->login_type;
    } 
    else
    {
        return false;      
    }

}
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because `$this->db` is not initialized, or simply because it has not been defined at the time of you invoking `get_login_type();`

Comment: I don't understand how it can't be initialized when I have it autoloaded.

Comment: Based on the code you have included, I can't give you any reasons. But maybe you can check this by logging `print_r($this->db)` and seeing what is the current value of `$this->db`.

Comment: Its still saying the same thing.

Comment: What I meant was to that code the only thing in your function and see exactly what the `db` field is holding. It might well be that there is a simple reference error.

Comment: I added that into the function and it still gave me that error.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear enough. You should change your function into: `function get_login_type() { print_r($this->db); }` and then inspect the output. If you are right and it has been initialized to the object, then you should get something like `[Object] ...`. If not, then it means the initialization part has not been called properly.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Kow_auth::$db

Filename: libraries/Kow_auth.php

Line Number: 19

Comment: Okay. I'm going on a limb here, but wasn't the `Kow_auth` class supposed to extend some other class which DOES include the `$db` field with a properly initialized value? Because you ARE calling `parent::__construct();`, but `Kow_auth` does NOT have any parent class.

Comment: oops I took that out. Let me add it real quick.

Comment: Dang I added that back in and it still says that error message.

Comment: Can you contact me via email please?